# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008 missing any instance of a server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

So i just installed the Server Management and when i try to connect to server it gives me an error. I went to SQL Server Configuration Manager and there i dont have nothing. I have empty lists where the server instances should be. So i dont have any running local server.

So someone can tell me how i'm suppose to set some server instance or what i'm doing wrong ?

I installed the Server Management on Windows 7, 32-bit OS, and i need exacly this version of 2008 and i dont need the updated versions at this point.

Comment: Did you install the server instance? You mention about installing the server management but not the server. Go back to the installer screen and make sure you install a server instance.

Comment: Have you installed a local server? SSMS does not automatically come with a SQL Server installation on the same box - you have to install SQL Server as well as SSMS if you want an instance on the same box.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Management tool is just a GUI for you SQL Server. SQL Server is a separate installation. If you are trying to control a remote SQL Server you will need to add that to the management UI, local servers should show up automatically if you install SQL Server locally.

Answer (score 0):

You can download SQL Server 2008 - Express Edition from [https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30438](http://Microsoft%C2%AE%20SQL%20Server%C2%AE%202008%20R2%20SP2%20-%20Express%20Edition)

It will install SQL Server which your Management Studio can connect.